# command line ical viewer

Tags: command-line, calendar, meetings

I don't use a mail reader that supports calendaring, but will often receive emails that have ical invitations in them.  They are a pain to try to read in plain text and parse though.  Is there a command line tool on Linux to view the calendar requests "prettily"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that I've not tried any of these so I can't be sure that they will do what you want.

---

I think that [calcurse](http://tuxdiary.com/2014/12/26/calcurse/) might do the job.

<s>[ical](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ical1.html) - An X based Calendar Program - OK so needs x-windows, not so good for your requirement</s>\
**NOTE:** The *ical* software does NOT support the *iCalendar* format!

These might do it but not clear if they support iCal:

- https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli
- https://github.com/tobixen/calendar-cli
- http://lostpackets.de/khal/

In addition, there is **[pal](http://palcal.sourceforge.net/)** but no sign of iCal support I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for anyone interested calcurse (of recent enough vintage at least) works as advertised here, and is what I'm going to go with